# exec executable sed

Tags: ant, sed, exec

Want to replace value in a txt file on macos using ant.
I used the following code, but its giving error: "The  type doesn't support nested text data (" ")".

```
<exec executable="sed">
   <arg value="s/old/new/g" />
   <arg value="$MY_FILE" />
 </exec>.
```

How to replace a value of an variable, I used replace for a file on windows, it works.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's a bit late, but I just found this question. Hopefully, my solution helps at least other people.

There is one parameter missing. sed on the commandline needs either -e "your expression" of -f "/path/to/your scriptfile". In case of ant usage, you want to change the file directly ("internally" in sed's speech), instead of different input / output files. So you need to add -i (or easier, change the -e  to -ie).
So, the correct invocation will be:

```
<exec executable="sed">
   <arg value="-ie" />
   <arg value="s/old/new/g" />
   <arg value="$MY_FILE" />
</exec>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help

ant-contrib PropertyRegex

Performs regular expression operations on an input string, and sets the results to a property

http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case I do not need to change my source file, and i need to change some paths into my log4j.properties. So here is my solution

```
<exec executable="sed">
        <arg value="s-/path/to/change/in/log4j_file-/new/path-g"/> 
        <arg line="./src/log4j.properties"/>
        <redirector output="./output/path/conf/log4j.properties" ></redirector>
</exec>
```

It is like this command:

```
sed 's-/path/to/change/in/log4j_file-/new/path/log-g' ./src/log4j.properties > ./output/path/conf/log4j.properties
```